# MNIST Data set up batch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am at the step of train the model. However, when I apply the code from a tutorial: `batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(50)`. It shows that there is no attribute 'train' in the TensorFlow model. I know it is outdated code, and I tried to convert to new version of TensorFlow. However, i couldn't find a matching code that can do the same thing as the above line of code do. I bet there is a way but I couldn't come up with one solution.

I found a method that asked me to use `tf.data.Dataset.batch(batch_size)`.
I tried the following way, but none of them works.

```
a. batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(50)

b. batch_x, batch_y =  tf.data.Dataset.batch(batch_size)

c. batch_x, batch_y =  tf.data.Dataset.batch(50)

d. batch_x, batch_y = mnist.batch(50)
```

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:

  #FIrst, run vars_initializer to initialize all variables
  sess.run(vars_initializer)

  for i in range(steps):

    #Each batch: 50 images
    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(50)

    #Train the model
    #Dropout keep_prob (% to keep): 0.5 --> 50% will be dropped out
    sess.run(cnn_trainer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_true: batch_y, hold_prob: 0.5})

    #Test the model: at each 100th step
    #Run this block of code for each 100 times of training, each time run a batch
    if i % 100 == 0:
      print('ON STEP: {}'.format(i))
      print('ACCURACY: ')

      #Compare to find matches of y_pred and y_true
      matches = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), tf.argmax(y_true, 1))

      #Cast the matches from integers to tf.float32
      #Calculate the accuracy using the mean of matches
      acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches, tf.float32))

      #Test the model at each 100th step
      #Using test dataset
      #Dropout: NONE because of test, not training. 
      test_accuracy = sess.run(acc, feed_dict = {x:mnist.test.images, y_true:mnist.test.labels, hold_prob:1.0})


      print(test_accuracy)
      print('\n')
```

Comment: You want to get batches from the MNIST dataset?

Comment: @ Shubham Panchal, yes, I am trying to get batch_x, and batch_y.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data`. It returns a tuple of Numpy arrays: `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)`.

After that, you need to create dataset object using Dataset API. This will create training dataset. Test dataset could be created in the same fashion.

```
train, test = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train[0], train[1]))
```

Then, to create batch, you need to apply batch function to it

```
dataset = dataset.batch(1)
```

To output it contents or use it in training you need to create iterator. Code below creates most common iterator and outputs element of `batch_size` in this case 1.

```
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

Please read https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets

Comment: Thank you Sharky! this makes sens to me! I also tried to downgrade my keras version to 1.12.0 or lower, and it works too! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

This uses TensorFlow 1.11.0 and Keras and intended to show how to use the `batch`. You have to adapt it to your need.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as k


(x_train, y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
X_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28,1)
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28,1)
Y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_test,10)


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, Y_test))
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(32)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

tbCallback = [
    k.callbacks.TensorBoard(
        log_dir="D:/TensorBoard", histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_images=True
    )
]


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs = 10, steps_per_epoch = 30,validation_data=test_dataset,validation_steps=1, callbacks=tbCallback)
```

Comment: Thank you Mohan, I tried to change my keras to an older version. and it works! Thank you very much!